# rgl: > Error in rgl.clear(type, subscene = subscene) : object 'rgl_clear' not found

Tags: r, rgl

Doing (R3.4, ubuntu 16.04, rgl 0.95.1441):

```
library(rgl)
    open3d()
```

returns:

```
Error in rgl.clear(type, subscene = subscene) : 
  object 'rgl_clear' not found

        x <- sort(rnorm(1000))
        y <- rnorm(1000)
        z <- rnorm(1000) + atan2(x, y)
        plot3d(x, y, z, col = rainbow(1000))

Error in currentSubscene3d() : object 'rgl_getsubsceneid' not found
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, kay.

For some reason doing:

```
apt-get install r-cran-rgl
```

doesn't install the latest package version for this one. (I *am* using 
 the external repository maintained by CRAN).

So this has to be solved the old way:

```
apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev
```

and then install rgl from source. Voila.

Answer (score 5):

You have probably recently upgraded R.  After an upgrade, you need to reinstall packages.  An easy way to do so is

```
update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, I had the same error message myself, on:

`R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) 
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS`

My first error message is the same as the OP's, but the second differs:

> Error in rgl.clear(type, subscene = subscene) :    object 'rgl_clear'
>   not found
>
> Error in rgl.getcolorcount() : object 'rgl_getcolorcount' not found

Just in case this helps anyone else, what fixed this issue for me was:

```
install.packages("rglwidget")
```